# What is practical meaning of T-forward Measure vs Risk-neutral Measure?

Tags: risk-neutral-measure

What I understand is that risk-neutral measure use Risk-free product as numeraire

and T-Forward measure use Bond Price as numeraire

reading material says, T-forward measure make the pricing behavior comfortable. The reason is it extract discount term(bond price) from Expectation symbol.

But I think although there is discount factor inside expectation symbol (when considering risk-neutral measure) we just use exp(-r*T) as discount factor right?

So I don't understand what is the practical meaning out of expectation because in risk-neutral pricing
discount factor(RiskNeutral) : exp(-r*T)
in T-forward measure
discount factor(T-forward) : exp(-r*T)

Above illustration is my idea.

Could you understand me what is my idea's fault and the practical of meaning?

It would be great if you suggest any real example.

Thanks.

Comment: If interest rates are stochastic, the price of a European call option  is $$\mathbb{E}_t^\mathbb{Q}\left[\exp\left(-\int_t^T r_s\text{d}s\right) \max\{S_T-K,0\}\right].$$ As you see, because $r_s$ is random too, this expectation depends on the _joint distribution_ of $r$ and $S$. This is quite difficult. You can't just use $e^{-rT}$. If bonds are traded, then the $\mathbb{Q}^T$ measure makes computations much easier, see [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/61159/41821). However, setting the bond price equal to $e^{-rT}$ implicitly assumes that $r$ is constant!

Comment: Thanks for reply. So, then our conventional pricing method : discount cashflow using zero curve from market quote (ex. STRIPS) is related T-forward measure?